# Function to locate a string in a text

Tags: c#, visual-c++

What would be the most efficient way of searching for a specific string in a text then displaying only a portion of it?

Here is my situation: I am currently hosting a .txt file on my server. The function I want to create would access this .txt (maybe even download for efficiency?), search an ID (ex. 300000000) and then put the name in a string (ex. Island Andrew).

Here is an example of the .txt file hosted on my server:

```
ID: 300000000 NAME: Island Andrew
ID: 300000100 NAME: Island Bob
ID: 300000010 NAME: Island George
ID: 300000011 NAME: Library
ID: 300000012 NAME: Cellar
```

I have already complete code for a similar example, however, the formatting is different and it is not in c#.

Here it is;

If anyone can help me accomplish this in c#, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a pure visual c++ to c# conversion question, it has nothing to do with winforms, I'm updating the tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "then displaying only a portion of it"? Which portion of string/text you want to display? The one that matches your id?

Comment: If I search for 300000000, it would put Island Andrew in a string @Grozz All the current answers do not seem to do it with the format I provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplistic approach without proper error handling.
Main part to look at is regex stuff.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var map = new Map();
        Console.WriteLine(map[300000011]);
    }
}

public class Map: Dictionary<int, string>
{
    public Map()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient()
        {
            Proxy = null
        };

        string rawData = wc.DownloadString("<insert url with data in new format here>");
        PopulateWith(rawData);
    }

    void PopulateWith(string rawText)
    {
        string pattern = @"ID: (?<id>\d*) NAME: (?<name>.*)";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(rawText, pattern)) 
        {
            // TODO: add error handling here
            int id = int.Parse( match.Groups["id"].Value );
            string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;

            this[id] = name;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner. Uses the new format! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to create an array of names in C#:

```
Dictionary<int,String> mapDictionary;
string[] mapNames = rawData.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(String str in mapNames)
{
    {
    String mapid = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(":"));
    String mapname = str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(':') + 1);
    mapDictionary.Add(Convert.ToInt32(mapid), mapname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work with the format of my .txt file located on my server? If so, this is the correct answer to my question!

Comment: Yes, I do believe it will. It's basically the code you had converted to c#.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove all carets (^)
- Convert all member access operators (->) to dots
- Change `gcnew` to `new` Convert array to `string[]`
- Remove private and public modifiers from class, have them on methods
- explicitly (e.g. `public void CacheMaps()`)
- Change `ref class` to `static class`
- Change `nullptr` to `null`
- Change `catch(...)` to only `catch`
- Move `using namespace` to the very top of the file, and replace scope resolution operator (::) to dots.

That should be about it.

Answer (score -1):

simplest way would be to do a token separator between ID: 30000 and Name: Andrew Island and remove the ID and Name as such

```
30000, Andrew Island
```

Then in your C# code you would create a custom class called

```
public class SomeDTO {
   public long ID{get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

next you would create a new List of type  SomeDTO as such:

```
var List = new List<SomeDTO>();
```

then as you're parsing the txt file get a file reader and read it line by line for each line ensure that you have a token separator that separates the two Values by the comma separation.

Now you can simply add it to your new List

```
var tempId = line[1];
var tempName = line[2];
List.Add(new SomeDTO{ ID = tempId, Name = tempName});
```

Now that you have the entire list in memory you can do a bunch of searching and what not and find all things you need plus reuse it because you've already built the list.

```
var first = List.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Andrew Island")).FirstOrDefault();
```